# LOAD DATA INFILE MYSQL Error

Tags: java, mysql

I'd like to load a file in a mysql table thrugh java program using load data infile command but I am receiving MySQL Syntax Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

The sql statement is the following:

```
 String sql =    "LOAD DATA  LOCAL INFILE '/Dataset/"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+".txt'" +
                            "    INTO TABLE data " +
                            "    CHARACTER SET utf8 " +
                            "    FIELDS " +
                            "        TERMINATED BY '|' " +
                            "    LINES " +
                            "    STARTING BY 'status' " +
                            "        TERMINATED BY '\n' " +
                            "    (@col_type, @col_origin, @col_text, @col_url, @col_id, @col_time, @col_retcount)"+
                            "     set userid = '1234' "
                            "      , original = @col_origin "+
                            "      , datatext = @col_text "+
                            "      , url = @col_url "+
                            "      , id = @col_id "+
                            "      , retcount = @col_retcount "+                                
                            "      , date = str_to_date(@col_time, '%m/%d/%Y') "+
                            "      , isanswer = CASE WHEN @col_origin LIKE '% abcd %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ";
```

My problem is that I cannot spot the error.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two backslashes (\) in your Java String near

```
"       Terminated By '\\n' " +
                        ^ new
```

Your String, then, would look like this:

```
String sql = "LOAD DATA "
        + " LOCAL INFILE '/Dataset/"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+".txt'"
        + "    INTO TABLE data "
        + "    CHARACTER SET utf8 "
        + "    FIELDS "
        + "        TERMINATED BY '|' "
        + "    LINES "
        + "    STARTING BY 'status' "
        + "        TERMINATED BY '\\n' "
        + "    (@col_type, @col_origin, @col_text, @col_url, @col_id, @col_time, @col_retcount)"
        + "     set userid = '1234' "
        + "      , original = @col_origin "
        + "      , datatext = @col_text "
        + "      , url = @col_url "
        + "      , id = @col_id "
        + "      , retcount = @col_retcount "
        + "      , date = str_to_date(@col_time, '%m/%d/%Y') "
        + "      , isanswer = CASE WHEN @col_origin LIKE '% abcd %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ";
```